# Represent graph in table and given visited nodes which nodes to visit next

Tags: database, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Say I have a graph with N nodes 111,222,...,nnn and I have the graph represented in the following table for example

```
NodeID  |   PredecessorID
222         111
333         111
555         222
555         333
```

and so on.

given a list of M nodes that have been visited how can I find all the nodes that are to be visited next? 
a node to be visited next is a node that all of its predecessors have been visited.

Comment: Does your list of visited noted contains all visited node or only a subset of them?

Answer (score 0):

If your list M contains all visited nodes and not only a subset of them you can do it like this:

```
foreach n in N:
    visite = True
    if n is not marked:
        foreach predecessor (pn) of n:
            visite = visite and (is pn marked)

    if visite = True:
        add n to visitable nodes
```

In the worst case the number of `predecessors of n` is `N` (complete Graph) so the runtime complexity of this is O(N^2)